# Return a checked-out license in MATLAB/Lincese Manager (Flexera Software)

Tags: matlab, licensing

I have a MATLAB server which hosts a license manager (`LMTOOLS by Flexera Software LLC`) and few clients.

When you run use a toolbox function such as `datestr(busdate(date))` you automatically checkout the Financial Instruments toolbox from the server.  The license is returned to the server only when you close the session. Is there a way to force a particular client to return the license? A user forgetting to close his/her session can affect everyone as the administrator has no way to return the license to the server.

You can use:

```
lmutil lmstat -a -c "MYPATH\network.lic" --> to check license-borrower details
Output: ......john.doe PCNAME PCNAME (vxx) (SERVER/3300 123), start Tue 8/5 10:30
```

I tried using:

```
lmutil lmremove -c "MYPATH\network.lic" Fin_Instruments_Toolbox john.doe PCNAME PCNAME
```

but it returned just 1 line output *lmutil - Copyright (c) 1989-2012 Flexera Software...* and did not check-in the borrowed license.  Any idea how to do this without closing the borrowing Matlab session? I even disconnected the client from the network but that didn't help.

Useful links: [weblink1](http://support1.geomagic.com/link/portal/5605/5668/Article/250/-Legacy-Why-is-my-floating-server-showing-my-license-is-checked-out-after-a-Geomagic-application-crash) [weblink2](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=us#!topic/comp.soft-sys.matlab/iEG7lks94JU)

Comment: I have run into this problem before and I don't believe you can. I know that I have gotten emails from my license administrator to ask me to close my session to free up a particular license. One time I actually had to reboot my computer to free it up. I looked into it at that time and found a link on the MathWorks site saying that it was not possible to check a license back in, but I can't find it at the moment.

Comment: If you think about it, though, if they did allow one to check in and out the licenses, there would be an enormous potential for abuse, because you could have 100 users and as long as they checked a toolbox in and out fast enough and had a way to not clash, the total number of licenses would be virtually meaningless. In fact, I think there is even something like a 30 minute minimum time limit on checking out a toolbox license, so if you open MATLAB, run `datestr(busdate(date))` from the command line, and then immediately exit, the license still waits before someone else can use it.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do that - the client has to close their MATLAB session.

Answer (score 0):

Mathworks use Flexnet and doesn't allow 'reread' or 'lmremove' like the other editors that use Flexnet. If I must make available a token I try the following solutions :

- stop/start of the license server;
- block the IP address of the computer where the toolbox is used.

**Start/stop** :
The users that have a token can use it during 20 minutes before lost it if the license server doesn't respond, but some new users can't take a token. Before make this, I check the number of Tcp/IP ports opened for the license service. I know that below 180/190 sessions (users), I can make a start/stop of the server.
If the faulty client doesn't make an other checkout after the start of the license server, the token will be available for other users.
If the user use a floating (CN) license and try to make an 'OUT' too rapidly (like a `while(1)`), I modify the option file to block the user by putting an 'EXCLUDE' for the user - a log file that grows continuously could be dangerous for the server. Or, if the user takes too many CN tokens for the same toolbox, I put a 'MAX' directive for him.

**Block the IP address** :
If the client using a token doesn't contact the server during 4 hours, the server consider that the token is 'Idle' and get it, it makes an 'IN', then the token is available. I use a 'Iptable' command to block the IP of the user's computer. This is only valid if the computer isn't shared between many users like a cluster node. The 4 hours is the value of the 'TIMEOUT' directive, but don't hope to reduce this value, even if you change it in the option file, you can only increase it. The minimum value is locked by Mathworks.